# Trying to make movie of 3D PCA plot (rgl) using movie3d

Tags: r, rgl

I have made a rgl 3D PCA plot in R using the pca3d package, and I am trying to make a gif file containing a movie of the rotating plot using movie3d. There is a function in the pca3d package (makeMoviePCA), that passes its arguments to movie3d. Here is the command I am using:

```
pca3d(pc, components = 1:3, title=TRUE, col=col_conditions, radius=2)

makeMoviePCA(dir="/Users/workdir", clean=TRUE, type = "gif", movie = "movie", convert=TRUE)
```

This plays the movie like I want to, but does not save it into a gif file, and displays the following error:

```
Writing 'movie100.png'
...
Writing 'movie120.png'

Error in system("convert --version", intern = TRUE) : 
  error in running command
sh: convert: command not found
```

**EDIT**: I fixed this by telling R where "convert" is by using

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("/opt/local/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed?

Comment: Yes, I do have ImageMagick installed

Comment: You might find something helpful [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/301359.html)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the error

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by telling R where "convert" is by using

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("/opt/local/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))
```