# An R package for 3D PCA (scores plot and loadings plot (arrow))?

Tags: r, 3d, pca

I have successfully run a 2D PCA with the prcomp code on R and a successful loadings plot by arrows for the PCA. However, I would like to visualize it in 3D, both my scores and loadings. I have experimented with the plot3D package using the arrow3D for loadings plot; however, this package doesn't have an ellipse function for my scores plot as I would like to add that so I may observe an overlap between groups.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to make movie of 3D PCA plot (rgl) using movie3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922770/trying-to-make-movie-of-3d-pca-plot-rgl-using-movie3d)

Comment: The `pca3d` function shows ellipses. See [page 4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pca3d/pca3d.pdf).